# JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace) at the start up of project in springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-jdbc

N.B This question might seem duplicate but I think this is not because in my case I am getting this error only in springboot 3 and during starting the project, not during actual transaction.

I am migrating from `springboot 2.7.5` to `3.0.6` . Without making change to code except `build.gradle` I am getting a new exception during project startup only when **debug mode is enabled**

```
023-06-15 12:30:23,839 DEBUG [main] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl:324 - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:324)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1003)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:866)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy147.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.hasNamedQuery(NamedQuery.java:115)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.lookupFrom(NamedQuery.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:180)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at com.Application.main(Nid1StreamsApplication.java:10)
```

My service class is annotated with `@Transactional` . Hibernate provides this message `JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only` when exception occurs. My question is

1. Why transactions is marked for rollback-only when there is no exception during project startup?
2. `exception just for purpose of providing stack trace`, does this mean I should ignore this exception?

**Edit**: I am getting this exception for each repo method. Before each exception I am getting logs like this

```
2023-06-19 11:04:53,967 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:225 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'countryRepo'
2023-06-19 11:04:53,968 DEBUG [main] o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler:302 - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-06-19 11:04:53,970 DEBUG [main] o.s.d.r.c.s.RepositoryFactorySupport:272 - Initializing repository instance for com.demo.repo.CountryRepo…
2023-06-19 11:04:53,971 DEBUG [main] o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler:302 - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2023-06-19 11:04:53,975 DEBUG [main] o.s.d.j.r.q.NamedQuery:141 - Looking up named query CountryRepo.findByName
```

Comment: Which interface are you extending in your repositories? With JPARepository findByName works fine for me.

Comment: Which springboot version?Repo extends this RootRepo  `public interface RootRepo<T,S> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T,S>, CrudRepository<T,S>,  JpaSpecificationExecutor { }`

Comment: This is because Spring Data JPA at startup will check if the query method is either a named query or needs to be parsed to generate a query. If not a named query it will generate the query, apparently the newer Hibernate now throws an error at debug level for this, wehre older versions don't. In short there is no such thing as "I only upgraded from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.0" as it will upgrade a lot more dependencies and libraries. But to answer your question in short, yes ignore this and don't enable debug :).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your answer. And yes migrating to v3 causes lots of side effect and dependency issues, i added this line so that people can reach conclusion faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes ignore this stacktrace as it is for information purpose only!

This is because Spring Data JPA, at startup, will check if the query method is either a named query or needs to be parsed to generate a query. If not a named query it will generate and validate the query.

Apparently the newer Hibernate version included in Spring Boot 3.x now throws an error at debug level for this. Where older versions didn't.

In short there is no such thing as "I only upgraded from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.0" as it will upgrade a lot more dependencies and libraries. For which you should read the changelogs as well (depending on the library/framework you might need to change other things as well!).