# Issue adding a custom method findEmail(String email) to the JpaRepository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm encountering an error when trying to add a custom method, findEmail(String email), to my AuthenticationRepository interface which extends JpaRepository in my Spring Boot application. Here's my code:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthenticationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

User Entity

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()   {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm facing:

```
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1076) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:954) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.hasNamedQuery(NamedQuery.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.getCountQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

I've tried adding @Query but still faced the same error.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
@Repository
public interface AuthenticationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

I've also tried removing the findByEmail method signature and the compiler runs without any error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace) at the start up of project in springboot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503698/jdbc-transaction-marked-for-rollback-only-exception-provided-for-stack-trace-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are supposed to return `List<User>` from `findByEmail(String email)`.

If you want only one `User` specify that it can be the **first** one to appear. In this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-findfirst-vs-findtop) you have more information on the subject.

Something like `User findFirstByEmailLike(String email)` should work.

Comment: Hey Orlando, Thank you for providing your feedback. I've attempted to use both List<User> and User findFirstByEmailLike(String email) but I'm still facing the same error. `@Repository
public interface AuthenticationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
 User findFirstByEmailLike(String email);
}
` `@Repository
public interface AuthenticationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
 List<User> findByEmail(String email);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled extended logging for Hibernate packages. This is not a real exception but just a trace for a debugging, and that's mentioned in the first line of the trace:

> java.lang.Exception: **exception just for purpose of providing stack trace**

Since the origin is `org.hibernate.resource...JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl` (see the second line of the trace), to get rid of the stack trace you may just set logging level to `INFO` for that package.

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        resource: INFO
```

in the `application.yml` or

```
logging.level.hibernate.resource=INFO
```

in case of `appication.properties`

You are free to increase or decrease the scope of that logging level (e.g. `org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal=INFO` won't affect packages above `internal`)

Comment: Thank you for explanation! It was quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same issue with `spring boot 3.2.2` with downgrade to `1.5.10.RELEASE` you'll get it to work, but everything else will break